# Pytest monkeypatching a decorated method, it also replaces the decorator

Tags: python, testing, pytest, monkeypatching

While I was testing some code with pytest, I needed to monkeypatch a method that was also decorated. I patched the method and while I expected the decorators being executed in the patched method, they weren't, so it looks like the patched method replaces everything.

Is this the normal behaviour?

I wrote a simplified example of the problem:

**functions.py**

```py
def mul_by(func):
    def wrapper(num):
        return func(num * 4)
    return wrapper


@mul_by
def show_number(n: int):
    print(n)
    return n
```

**test_functions.py**

```py
import sys
from src.functions import show_number


def test_show_number(monkeypatch):

    def mocked_show_number(num: int):
        print('Mocked func')
        return 5

    monkeypatch.setattr(sys.modules[__name__], 'show_number', mocked_show_number)
    assert show_number(2) == 20
```

**Output**

```
collected 1 item

test/test_functions.py F                                                                                                                                                                             [100%]

================================================================================================= FAILURES =================================================================================================
_____________________________________________________________________________________________ test_show_number _____________________________________________________________________________________________

monkeypatch = <_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch object at 0x10b7e5d00>

    def test_show_number(monkeypatch):

        def mocked_show_number(num: int):
            print('Mocked func')
            return 5

        monkeypatch.setattr(sys.modules[__name__], 'show_number', mocked_show_number)
>       assert show_number(2) == 20
E       assert 5 == 20
E        +  where 5 = show_number(2)

test/test_functions.py:11: AssertionError
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mocked func
========================================================================================= short test summary info ==========================================================================================
FAILED test/test_functions.py::test_show_number - assert 5 == 20
```

The decorator simply multiplies the number by 4, and in the monkeypatched method I hardcode the value just to return 5, so I'd expect 20 in the result. But, 5 is returned, the monkeypatched method's value.

Can someone point if there is any error in this way to monkeypatch or if it is the desired behaviour?

Comment: Why would you expect the decorator to be applied to your mock function? You are replacing the *entire* function `show_number` by your mock, not just the “inner” one. If you want to decorate your mock function, you will need to do so explicitly.

Comment: You are monkeypatching the function in its module, but you have imported the original into your test module already. Even if you would be calling the function in the module: what sense does it make to test a mock?

Comment: Thank you @KonradRudolph for the response. That's exactly what I'm curious about and I didn't found a clear explanation.

Comment: @KlausD. I'm not testing the mock, I'm just using the mock to simulate (raise) some errors that may be handled in the decorator. But as **Konrad Rudolph** pointed, I'm not using the right strategy.

Comment: Of cause you are testing the mock. You mock `show_number` and then you call `show_number` and assert the result. You should never call a mock in your test directly. The mock should replace functions called by the function you are testing (dependencies).